# Notepad++ conditional Macro

Tags: macros, conditional-statements, notepad++

I'd like to search for a string starting with `doi = {` or `url = {` and then remove it from the file. For example, for the following data I'd like to remove the `url` and subsequently `doi` sections.

I don't know how I can use the `replace` command, as I don't know the complete string, and for `Macro`, how can I do this if these lines are not at regular distance from each other?

```
@article{Carrion2006,
author = {Carrion, M. and Arroyo, J.M.},
doi = {10.1109/TPWRS.2006.876672},
journal = {IEEE Trans. Power Syst.},
title = {{Bla Bla Bla 1}},
pages = {1371--1378},
url = {http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/lpdocs/epic03/wrapper.htm?arnumber=1664974},
year = {2006}
}
@article{Chandrasekaran2012,
author = {Chandrasekaran, K. and Hemamalini, S. and Simon, Sishaj P. and Padhy, Narayana Prasad},
issn = {03787796},
journal = {Electr. Power Syst. Res.},
pages = {109--119},
publisher = {Elsevier B.V.},
title = {{Bla Bla Bla 2}},
url = {http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0378779611002471},
volume = {84},
year = {2012}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

Find what: `^(?:doi|url)\s*=\s*[^}]+\},\R`
Replace with: NOTHING